# How to move all data in an Excel file downwards when entering new data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I use Excel to take notes for my work as I find it really easy to manage and look for the information I want instantly, you already know that Excel has the best-in-class indexing mechanism right? also it gives me the chance to find duplicates and adjust it the way I want.

Well then I have run into a trouble as time goes by, the note grows into a sheet with thousands of row and every time I need to put new data in, I have to scroll all the way down to type, now this becomes a struggle when your phone doesn't keep the Excel app in background and you have to take notes multiple times a day. My sheet has a few hundred thousands rows now and multiple columns, I want all of them to automatically move downwards (except for the first title line) before I type in new data in a new line.

I would highly appreciate it if someone could help me get over this.

Cheers!

Comment: *move downwards (except for the first title line) before I type in new data in a new line.* And how does you want Excel to determine that you want to enter something now?

Comment: Recommendation: lock line 1 so that it is always on the screen. Create a button that moves focus to the end of the data (scrolls down to the end of the filled range) and press it each time you need to enter new data.

Comment: question about smartphones (which seems to be the case now) are off-topic here.

Comment: Not only on mobile, I also need that on PC too.

Comment: " I want all of them to automatically move downwards" do you mean insert new row ? || another one : you can use <Ctrl> + <DownArrow> shortcut to go to the down most row.

Answer (score 0):

Select a cell, presumably the leftmost cell, in the row you want to be using all the time.

When you need to enter a new note, press "Shift-Space Bar" to highlight that line.

Then press "Ctrl-+" (Control and the plus sign on the numberpad, OR press "Ctrl-Shift-+" using the plus sign on the main keyboard). This will insert a line.

No one who has typed "a few hundred thousands rows" will mind pressing two quick key combinations. And being on, or getting to, that row will hardly be a chore since you are on it now typing your current note. So selecting it should never be any trouble at all, literally, no work at all.

It appears you might be using a phone version, and who knows if it is actual MS Excel or one of the many look-a-likes? However, the phone version (oops... "mobile" "app"...) will have easy to find out corresponding shortcuts for both selecting the row AND for inserting a row.

Lastly, if using a phone, surely you will someday need to consider reducing the hundreds of thousands of rows to a manageable number by removing or archiving the ones that have been acted upon. Phones have limited memory and less to spend on running each application so with a huge load of data and formatting to pile into the memory available for running the program, you could have an issue someday.

Comment: Thank you very very much to all of you!! I totally forgot about this, but now I will definitely try again. I modified the Android Excel app to automatically scroll down to the bottom every time I open an Excel file, but would love to use the official app again. Thanks, guys, always be strong and healthy!